# Springboot java oracle procedure calling with cursor

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, stored-procedures

I am a new in spring world. 
I have a question about what is the better way to call a procedure from oracle package and return a CURSOR to a Spring?

I can do that like in classical java using "Callable Statement", but I think that there are any better, more cleaner ways, how to do that?

For example,

a) We have a simple table PEOPLE_TAB, where are :

NAME: NEO, Mary 
SURNAME: ANDERSON, Smith
SEX: M, W 
AGE: 20, 25 
ROLL:TEST, TEST

b) Also, we have a package HOME_TEST_PKG with procedure

> PROCEDURE show_people_data(
>      i_name     IN    VARCHAR2, 
>      o_resp_set OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
>
> IS
>
> BEGIN
>
> dbms_output.put_line('Hello  1');
>
> OPEN o_resp_set FOR SELECT name, surname, sex, age, roll from people where 
>   name=i_name;
>
> dbms_output.put_line('Hello  2');
>
> EXCEPTION
>       WHEN OTHERS
>       THEN
>
> ```
> dbms_output.put_line('Hello  3');
>
> OPEN o_resp_set FOR SELECT 'something wrong' as error from dual;
> ```
>
> END show_people_data;

c) then, we have a sample java code, which works in Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/DBtest")
@ResponseBody
public Map DBtest() throws SQLException {

private String PROCEDURE_NAME = "{call test.home_test_pkg.show_people_data(?,?)}";

    JSONObject answer = new JSONObject();
    CallableStatement stmt = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;
    String testNameNeo="NEO"; --simple check input for procedure
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "testname", "testpass");
        stmt = conn.prepareCall(PROCEDURE_NAME);
        stmt.setString(1, testNameNeo);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        stmt.execute();
        rset = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(2);

        while (rset.next()) {
            String name = rset.getString(1);
            log.info(name);
            answer.put("name",rset.getObject(1).toString());
            answer.put("surname",rset.getObject(2).toString());
        }
    }catch (Exception a){
        log.error("Exception "+a);
    }finally {
        rset.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    return Collections.singletonMap("response", answer);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to create a repository interface using @Procedure annotation like the example below.

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

  @Procedure(name = "test.home_test_pkg.show_people_data")
  List<MyEntity> getPeopleData(@Param("my_param_in") String myParamIn);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot integrates two technologies for working with relational databases:

1. JPA / Hibernate
2. JdbcTemplate

Both technologies can make use of Oracle cursors.

For *JPA / Hibernate*, there's a good example: [How to call Oracle stored procedures and functions with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/)

For JdbcTemplate, have a look at: [Spring - Returning REF Cursor from a SimpleJdbcCall](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/simple-jdbc-ref-cursor/)

Comment: Ringo Store! Thank you for the idea! I have tried both ways and I have found the SimpleJdbc is better way. 

For Other things I have tried JPA, also nice! thank you!!