# how do i import oracle database packages in spring boot.?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

`cus.sMB_PACKAGE.EABAL(new_aseid,to_date('&1','dd-mm-yyyy')-1)`

I want to import and use this oracle db package in my spring boot application but I don't know how to do it properly.

how do I import and use database packages in spring application.

Comment: Hello! You want to get some data from your db and properly transform it to LocalDateTime with pattern parameter to  Entity object?

Comment: You don't import packages into Spring Boot you just execute them through JDBC.

Comment: can I get a sample example.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Springboot java oracle procedure calling with cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597107/springboot-java-oracle-procedure-calling-with-cursor)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `@Repository` class in your project.

Here is a link with a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa) how to do it in spring and here is a link with a [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) to make your own pattern to `LocalDateTime.class` or `LocalDate.class`.
After that you can make some `@Service` classes which are using your repository method to do with your data all you want. Example how to use `@Service` annotation is [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-repository-service). Than you can create a `@Procedure` with your SQL statement, example is [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures).

Hope it helps.